# How to remove all the white spaces between two words?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

I have an input field on which the user types the city name, but what if the user types the city like this:

```
"New    York     "
"  New York           "
```

I used the trim function but that did not work, any suggestion?

```js
const city = "New         York     ";

console.log(city.trim());
```

How can I remove all the white spaces so I can save the city in the state as "New York"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace all consecutive space characters with one space:

```js
const str = "New    York     "
"  New York           "

const res = str.replace(/\s+/gm, " ").trim()

console.log(res)
```

Alternatively, you can split the string by a space, filter out the empty items, then join back by a space:

```js
const str = "New    York     "
"  New York           "

const res = str.split(" ").filter(e=>e).join(" ")

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine the `string.replace()` method and the RegEx and replace it with a single string. Notice the starting and ending spaces will be kept and stripped down to a single space. Trim any surrounding spaces from the string using JavaScript’s `string.trim()` method

```js
const city = "    New         York     ";

console.log(city.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim());
```